# MongoDB grouping returns only one document, even though it matches many documents?

Tags: mongodb

I am testing the [grouping](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group) feature in mongodb.

The group function takes an object as an argument. Within the object they have a key called `cond` of which value can be used as query to match documents.

I am passing a valid query that matches more than one document. But grouping returns only the last matched document's result. I think i am missing something here to make `group` function return all the matched documents results.

The steps i have done are,

```
db.test.insert({user:{name:"xxxx1"}});
db.test.insert({user:{name:"xxxx2"}});
db.test.insert({user:{name:"xxxx3"}});
db.test.insert({user:{name:"xxxx4"}});
db.test.insert({user:{name:"xxxx5"}});
db.test.insert({user:{name:"xxxx6"}});


db.test.group({
    initial:{name:'', id:''}, 
    reduce:function(d, o){o.name = d.user.name; o.id=d._id;}, 
    finalize:function(o){}, 
    cond:{"user.name":/^x/}
    });
```

The above command returns

```
[ 
  {  
    "name" : "xxxx6", "id" : ObjectId("4edf72baec65faac52976e72") 
  } 
]
```

Its the last inserted document.

What should i to  get all the matched results!?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"return all the matched documents results" means you probably want to do a query instead of a group. Grouping would be used to aggregate documents based on a key instead of simply returning all of the ones that match (what you want).

Just do `db.collection.find(query-document)`, which in your case would be:

```
db.test.find({"user.name": /^x/})
```

**Update to address new information:**

"i dont want to send complete document"

Then use the second parameter of find in order to provide a document that has the fields you want `{ "user.name": 1 }`. Keep in mind that _id is included by default but you can exclude it if you want using `{_id: 0}`.

As for the formatting, if storing the ordering is important then use an array. If order doesn't matter and it is for display purpose only do the ordering on the client side. Using map reduce to format the output is not the intended use and will only serve to slow the query down.

Comment: Actually the query result will be used for auto complete purpose, but i dont want to send complete document for that and i also wanted to format the query result into standard for {id:'', name:'', email:'' photo:''}. Earlier i was doing the formatting manually(fetching the query result and looping over all the result documents and creating the new format). Later i came to know that i could do it using mongo itself. And thats what i am trying to do in there. I am just using the query to fetch all the matched documents and trying to format them using grouping. Is that possible with mongo!

Comment: Are you sure `Using map reduce to format the output is not the intended use and will only serve to slow the query down` about this. Because already i am doing everything that you told. I have to format the data to generalize and get a common pattern from various collections. If have to generalize the query result to a common format, manually i have write code in various places. Instead i prefer the DB to do it.

Comment: I am hardly remeber that, similar kind of thing can be achieved from relational databases. I think its `as` keyword used in `RDBMS` to get the result as i need in mongo. I thought `mongo grouping` is similar to that. Now, i guess i am wrong. Thanks for your concern pal.